# Does someone have used Network Emulator API exposed in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, mstest, software-quality

I have seen VS2010 exposing Network Emulator API. I have installed it and trying to use this API, but not able detect whether it is really running with this code or not. Sometime I have given wrong profile name but it does not throw any error. Please find below my piece of code. If some one have used it please help me.

```
IntPtr m_emulatorHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
NetworkEmulationApi.LoadProfile(m_emulatorHandle, "300KB_WithLatency.xml");
NetworkEmulationApi.StartEmulation(m_emulatorHandle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. After lot of binging I found Ivan post on this. If anyone want to see it please visit [here](http://neganov.blogspot.com/2010/01/stand-alone-network-emulator-for-vs2010.html)

Basically in VS2010 release version they have modified the earlier API and if we use Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.NetworkEmulation dll will solve all problems.

Thanks,
Pritam